# Is there way I can fake a fk in django

Tags: python, django

One of the django apps is using a database that django isn't maintaining. In these tables, the DBA decided not use FK's instead just use Int fields.

Is there a way I can pretend these are foreignkeys in django app? I would like to use the orm still.

For example, the tables look like this

```
class PrimaryTable(models.Model):
     global_id = models.BigAutoField(db_column='_id', primary_key=True)

class RelatedTable(models.Model):
     global_id = models.BigIntegerField()  # this is the id for the primary table
     title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Is there way I can put a flag on the fields? Or can Django support joins that aren't specified as a FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't care if they are "real" foreign keys or not. Just create your foreign key as normal.

```
global = models.ForeignKey('PrimaryTable')
```

Comment: This was it. I kept naming the field global_id which was then causing django to look for the global_id_id column. Thank you!